# Hibernate (not JPA) Criteria - org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate `Criteria` to get max value from column `mobileno` in my table.

But when I'm getting the result, it throws an exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: mobileno of:
```

My table bean properties is:

```
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="code")
private   String  code;


@Column(name="mobileno")
private   String  mobileno;
//Setters and Getters
```

Hibernate Code:

```
@Override
public long getMaxMobileNo() {
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Data.class);     
criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("mobileno"));        
return  (long) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

where am I going wrong, how do I get the max value from my Table???

Comment: "max" on a `String` type?!

Comment: @nobeh: Yes. that is the problem?

Comment: Projections.max = A property maximum value. What excactly should the maximum value of mobileno be? I don't know projections but is seems to be for numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Its a workaround, but why dont you use

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name");
```

Every hibernate version will fast that way.